# Is this a safe tool for adding Remote Desktop server to Windows 7 Home?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I'm trying to set up the Microsoft Remote Desktop feature on a computer running Windows 7 Home, and came across this tool:

> [How To Enable Remote Desktop Connection In Windows 7 Home Premium Edition](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-enable-remote-desktop-connection-in-windows-7-home-premium-edition/)

Is this tool safe to use? Has anyone around here used it with any success?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used *that* tool so I can't attest to its safety.  Personally, I use [this one](http://thegreenbutton.com/forums/t/79427.aspx).  The Green Button people (Media Center fans) have been making them for a long time now, so it's pretty trust-worthy IMO.

**Warning** - Keep in mind that doing this invalidates your Windows license. :)

Comment: Thanks!  That tool seems to be a lot simpler, and having someone with a high reputation score recommending it gives me a lot more confidence in it.  I will run a few experiments with it on test systems soon.

Comment: Thank you also for pointing out the invalidation of a Windows license.  I have a few to spare that I don't mind if one becomes "non-activatable" just to satisfy my curiosity.  =D

Comment: Unfortunately Green Button has been acquired by Microsoft and the link in this answer now leads to a generic page on Microsoft Community.

Answer (score 4):

- Patching `termsrv.dll` should be safe (I have this on my XP boxen and it works well), but *make a backup* just in case.

  I don't know if the tool you found actually *patches* the file, or *replaces* it entirely with a pre-patched copy. The latter can cause some problems (for example, version mismatch).

  See techie007's answer for a different patcher (which appears to actually *patch* the file; but I personally haven't used either of them.)
- **Do not *ever* use the "enable blank password logon" option.** You have been warned.

Comment: +1 for the warning. Using any remote application like VNC without a password and you WILL have someone connect and take advantage of it. I learned this the hard way. People are out there scanning open ports for unprotected RDP-type apps every minute of every day.

Comment: Excellent answer!  I'd like to flag this one as an accepted answer as well, but it seems I can only turn one checkmark green and so I have to give it to techie007's answer because the link provided with the answer leads to a tool that appears to be very easy to use.  I really like both answers -- they're both very helpful.

Comment: @RandolfRichardson Does your RDP client still work? After last windows update, mine is no more connecting. I wonder id this is only happened to me.